# Bind to Color of a Brush

Tags: wpf, binding, brush

I am trying to animate the Fill property of a path.  What I have so far is a ColorAnimation that works well.  The target property is (Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color) and I set it to a value of "#999999"  (just an example color).

The problem comes from the fact that I'd like to set the value to "{TemplateBinding Background}".  Since Background is a brush and the property I'm targeting is a color this just results in no color in the animation.

I would be happy if I could just figure out how to set the value to the color portion of the background brush.  Any ideas?

BTW, this is in a control template for a ToggleButton.

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a class that implements [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx), and set this as the `Converter` property of the binding. You would still set the binding to the `Background`, but that would in turn be passed to your converter. The converter can extract the color from the brush, and then return that.

Comment: Yes, Value Converters are perfect for this kind of stuff.